# Ngrx conditional swtichMap dispatching multiple actions

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Webstorm is giving me an error:

> TS2345: Argument of type (res: any) =>  Types of property 'type' are incompatible. Type '"CLOSE_ACTIVE_CHATS"' is not assignable to type '"DELETE_SELECTED_CHAT"'.

#### On my inner switchMap

```
switchMap((res) => {//error here
  chat.mdRef.close();
  if (chat.chat.state === 2) {
    return [new CloseOpenChat(chat.chat._id), new 
      DeleteSelectedChat(), 
      new AddClosedChat(chat.chat)];
  })
```

#### Full code

```
@Effect()
closeChat: Observable<any> = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(CLOSE_CHAT_CALL),
  map((action: _Actions.AddClosedChat) => {
    return action.payload;
  }),
  switchMap((chat: CloseChatI) => {
    return this.messageService.closeChat(chat.chat._id).pipe(
      // @ts-ignore
      switchMap((res) => {
        chat.mdRef.close();
        if (chat.chat.state === 2) {
          return [new CloseOpenChat(chat.chat._id), new 
            DeleteSelectedChat(), 
            new AddClosedChat(chat.chat)];
        }
        return [new CloseActiveChat(chat.chat._id), new 
          DeleteSelectedChat(), 
          new AddClosedChat(chat.chat)];
      }),
      catchError(ErrorService.handleError)
    );
  }),
  catchError((err) => of(new CallFailed())
  )
);
```

Comment: The error you are getting is from the TypeScript compiler, not Webstorm - and it's probably a valid type error. Could you put up a Stackblitz with all your @ngrx code so I can have a look?

Comment: thanks for the formating, its my first post here. Its a project for work with about 5000 lines,I dont think i am allowed to post it. When I make @ts-ignore, it works fine. Its easy to reproduce though: when a switchMap conditionally returns actions, it gives this error

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `DeleteSelectedChat()` also dispatches an action, which leads to multiple actions dispatched.

If you comment out `DeleteSelectedChat()` do you still get the error?

Comment: the point of using a switchMap here is to dispatch multiple actions at once, dispatching a single action i.e using a map works fine with the conditional

Comment: @jensen effects should only dispatch a single actions, dispatching more would be considered an anti-pattern of ngrx. It is still possible, https://medium.com/@amcdnl/dispatching-multiple-actions-from-ngrx-effects-c1447ceb6b22

Comment: I did not know that, and i found plenty of tutorial showing how to dispatch multiple actions, in my case when I return only a single statement for example:
 `return [new CloseOpenChat(chat.chat._id), newDeleteSelectedChat(),  new AddClosedChat(chat.chat)];`
without the if statement, i don't get any typescript error.

Comment: What happens if you put the second return statement in an `else` statement in the above if condition?

Comment: NGRX developer calling it an anti-pattern: https://twitter.com/mikeryandev/status/938108618133602304?lang=en

Comment: tried nothing happens, Thanks but is there a way to dispatch multiple action that is not anti pattern?